# Python Requests: How to get value of Blank Hidden Input

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape this site: https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/f?p=1004:203

The missing piece of the puzzle is figuring out how to "get" the `p_request` parameter in the data payload prior to making the final request. This field comes up empty when looking at the "main" page, so cannot use that to pass through to my POST request.

The code below doesn't work because I have a blank `p_request` parameter in the payload, although I know through testing with developer console that it will work if I am able to get the `p_request` field.

```
# Query Main Site to Build Payload
url = 'https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/f?p=1004:203'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

# Get Cookie
cookies = {}
cookdat = r.cookies
cookies['ORA_WWV_APP_1004'] = cookdat.get('ORA_WWV_APP_1004')
cookies['X-Oracle-BMC-LBS-Route'] = cookdat.get('X-Oracle-BMC-LBS-Route')

# Create Payload
inputs = soup.select('input')
d_inputs = {i['id']:i.get('value','') for i in inputs}

data = [
  ('p_flow_id', '1004'),
  ('p_flow_step_id', '203'),
  ('p_instance', '%s'%d_inputs['pInstance']),
  ('p_debug', ''),
  ('p_request', ''),
  ('p_widget_name', 'worksheet'),
  ('p_widget_mod', 'PULL'),
  ('p_widget_action', ''),
  ('p_widget_num_return', '100000'),
  ('x01', '8980043036046866'),
  ('x02', '8985720770049096'),
  ('f01', 'R8980010866046866_column_search_current_column'),
  ('f01', 'R8980010866046866_search_field'),
  ('f01', 'R8980010866046866_row_select'),
  ('f02', ''),
  ('f02', ''),
  ('f02', '50'),
  ('p_json', '{"pageItems":{"itemsToSubmit":[{"n":"P203_LASTNAME","v":"%s"},{"n":"P203_FIRSTNAME","v":""},{"n":"P203_SEARCH_CRITERIA","v":"1"}],"protected":"%s","rowVersion":"","formRegionChecksums":[]},"salt":"%s"}'%(letter,d_inputs['pPageItemsProtected'],d_inputs['pSalt'])),
]

# POST request retrieve data
r = requests.post('https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/wwv_flow.ajax', cookies=cookies, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

In developer console, I see this field appears when making the type of submission I want, even though it is blank in the main page:

[image: screenshot of dev console]

How do I "retrieve" this field, which is necessary for the request to work?

Comment: What are you trying to scrape from that page? What problem you are facing? We don't have time to go through all of the code you have provide and check every single line. So, please try to give enough detail about in very easy way,I am trying to do this, here's my code, I am facing this problem, I have this idea and I found this while doing research.

Comment: I have found pattern of parameter `p` is like this in first `1004:203:` is always same ie. untill they update manually but that is also is in `<html>` tag. Like this `<html class="page-203 app-1004" lang="en"><head>` and after `:` there si 14 random number which will be different for every search that can be found in `input` tag of id `pInstance` but here's the twist

Comment: when you submit you `form` then in first it sends request+data you gave in your `data`  variable to `https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/wwv_flow.accept` and only redirect to that website which has those parameter. So, I think you also have to send that changed data to `flow_accept` and then only you can get the result in parameter website. Parameter website mean : `https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/f?p=1004:203:18186253354351::NO:::` url with all that parameter which you are tying to send.

Comment: Thanks for taking a deeper look! Yeah I saw that too, initial POST goes to flow_accept, and I assumed I’d get the instance_id from the response of the post. However what I’m noticing from playing around on the site is that the instance_id remains constant even if I change the search term, but somehow doing the search changes the state of the instance where if I Request that instance_id, I get the data for the new search term. Eg. if I go and submit (in browser) a new search, then pull the instance_id in Python it returns the new data even though the instance_id has not changed.

Comment: Yeah! I have noticed that too. And I think they save it in their server or in `web-storage`. But main thing, is your problem solved or not?

Comment: You can try using `selenium` rather then `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. I had tried my best to scrape but i am unsuccessful. https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-python-8a60f4cf40ab here's the link to start with.

Comment: If you also changed the mind to use `selenium` or other library then either mention it in answer or try to close question, but writing in answer is good mention that you have changed into using `selenium` and if you successfully scrape then try to add your code also.

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work, I'll update this comment, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I've dug in a bit more and refined my question. I still cannot get it to work

Comment: @DavidYang for me `p_request` was `Search` everytime I tried, which seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That work for me

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# globals
users = []
letter = "A"

# session
session = requests.Session()

# get page
auth = session.get('https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/f?p=1004:203')
soup = BeautifulSoup(auth.text, 'html.parser')

inputs = soup.select('input')
d_inputs = {i['id']: i.get('value', '') for i in inputs}

# create params
params = {
  'p_flow_id': d_inputs['pFlowId'],
  'p_flow_step_id': d_inputs['pFlowStepId'],
  'p_instance': d_inputs['pInstance'],
  'p_debug': '',
  'p_request': 'Search',
  'p_reload_on_submit': d_inputs['pReloadOnSubmit'],
  'p_page_submission_id': d_inputs['pPageSubmissionId'],
  'p_json': json.dumps({"pageItems": {
    "itemsToSubmit": [
      {"n": "P203_LASTNAME", "v": "{}".format(letter)},
      {"n": "P203_FIRSTNAME", "v": ""},
      {"n": "P203_SEARCH_CRITERIA", "v": "1"}
    ],
    "protected": d_inputs['pPageItemsProtected'],
    "rowVersion": "",
    "formRegionChecksums": []
    },
    "salt": d_inputs['pSalt']
  })
}

# Send request to APEX
session.post(
  'https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/wwv_flow.accept', data=params
)

# get page with data (first)
data_page = session.get(
  'https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/f?p=1004:203:{}::NO:::'.format(
    d_inputs['pInstance']
  )
)

table_soup = BeautifulSoup(data_page.text, 'html.parser')

# new params
inputs = table_soup.select('input')
d_inputs = {i['id']: i.get('value', '') for i in inputs}
json_ajax_data = json.loads(data_page.text.split(
    'interactiveReport('
)[1].split(');})();')[0])

# get data for next pages
params_news = {
    'p_flow_id': params['p_flow_id'],
    'p_flow_step_id': params['p_flow_step_id'],
    'p_instance': params['p_instance'],
    'p_debug': '',
    'p_request': 'PLUGIN={}'.format(json_ajax_data['ajaxIdentifier']),
    'p_widget_name': 'worksheet',
    'p_widget_mod': 'ACTION',
    'p_widget_action': 'PAGE',
    'p_widget_action_mod': 'pgR_min_row=51max_rows=50rows_fetched=50',
    'p_widget_num_return': 50,
    'x01': d_inputs['R8980010866046866_worksheet_id'],
    'x02': d_inputs['R8980010866046866_worksheet_id'],
    'p_json': params['p_json']
}

# get next page data
next_page = session.post(
  'https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/wwv_flow.ajax', data=params_news
)

next_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(next_page.text, 'html.parser')
next_page_table_with_data = table_soup.find('table', {'class': 'a-IRR-table'})
next_page_rows = next_page_table_with_data.find_all('tr')

# parse rows
for row_next_page in next_page_rows:
  cells_next_page = row_next_page.find_all('td')
  if len(cells_next_page) > 0:
    users.append(
      {
        'name': cells_next_page[0].text, 'surname': cells_next_page[1].text
      }
    )

print(users)
```

```
[
   {'name': 'ANDERSON', 'surname': 'MICHAEL L AND KAREN'}, 
   {'name': 'ALVAREZ', 'surname': 'PETRA'},
   ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works to get the first page of results which I am able to do, but I would like to get all results by toggling the option to list "all" through the `https://case.occ.ok.gov/ords/wwv_flow.ajax` , which seems to require another piece of information: `p_request`

Comment: @DavidYang sorry man, I change my code to wotk with `wwv_flow.ajax`

Comment: The part where you extract the `json_ajax_data` is the missing piece I was looking for! Working for me now, although I am not using your method of going page by page, but instead setting the page length to 100000